# Why stopping animation in code behind doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, code-behind

I have animation defined in XAML

```
<Storyboard x:Key="slide">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:30"
                             From="{Binding Width,
                                            ElementName=canvas}"
                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                             Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                             To="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                          ElementName=txtKron,
                                          Converter={StaticResource MultiplyConverter},
                                          ConverterParameter='-1'}" />
        </Storyboard>
```

which is triggered by:

```
<StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.SizeChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
```

I would like to stop animation when some text's lenght is lower than 15. I do it in code behind on text's setter:

```
Storyboard animation = (Storyboard)stack.Resources["slide"];

            if(value.Length > 15)
            {
                animation.Begin();
            }
            else
            {
                animation.Stop();
            }
```

But it doesn't work, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is "isControllable" set to true? This storyboard property prevents e.g. stopping if set to false (which is the default setting)

EDIT: It´s possible to set it via code

```
animation.Begin(this.MyContainer, true);
```

The second parameter sets the isControllable

Comment: Storyboard animation = (Storyboard)stack.Resources["slide"];
                if(value.Length > 15)
                {
                    animation.Begin(this, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    animation.Stop();
                }

Doesn't work

Comment: I didn´t find a possibility to set it in XAML. But I used a code behind version before which worked, see the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the storyboard to be stopped from codebehind, it should also be started on codebehind (with `Begin()`) and not triggered by an event in XAML as you are doing now.

Try assigning the `Loaded` and `SizeChanged` events to a codebehind event which calls the `Begin` method (using the container as a first parameter, and a second parameter of `true`), and then try to `Stop` it, instead of using `EventTriggers` and `BeginStoryboard`.

More info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741997(v=vs.110).aspx):

> To make a storyboard controllable, you use the Begin method and specify true as the second parameter.

Since you are using `EventTriggers` and `BeginStoryboard` to start it, `Storyboard.Stop` won't do anything

**Update**: I haven't tested this, but the MSDN on [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744905(v=vs.110).aspx) says that it you give a `Name` to `BeginStoryboard`, you make it controllable, so you might aswell try that. I doubt it'll work "as is", my guess is that you'd need to reach the `BeginStoryboard` object, and not the `Storyboard` one, but this is just a guess, and it's a simple modification worth a try